# Chrome plugin to replace image

Tags: jquery, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I am currently playing around with Chrome extensions development. I love cats and I'm trying to replace images that live on websites that use an `img` tag with an image of a cat (source: my plugin, "images" folder). I am not too sure what I'm doing wrong, but the image is not being displayed (I get the "broken" icon that is being displayed when it cannot find a path to the image).

This is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").append('HI THIS IS DOG');  //added this as test and it works - DOGS EVERYWHERE
    var cat = chrome.extension.getURL("cat.jpg");
    $('img').each(function(index, image){  //this produces "broken" icon
        $(image).attr('src', cat);
    });
});
```

This is my manifest:

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "I love cats",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "My life is complete, cats everywhere!",
    "browser_action": {
    "name": "I love cats",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "css": ["basic.css"],
    "js": [ "jquery-1.12.0.min.js", "contentscript.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

Does my image live in incorrect place? Or am I required to add it somehow to the manifest? I tried using png, but I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: You can add resources to the manifest, but the most important part is to get the URI for the image right, which you haven't.

Comment: @adeneo This is not exactly a constructive comment you gave. Could you please elaborate about what is wrong and how to fix it? So that we all learn? Thanks!

Comment: @arkascha - clearly the URL is wrong, there is no `cat.jpg` at that location. What the correct location for that image is, only the OP knows, I can't possible know that ?

Comment: @adeneo So basically what you said is: "seems not to work." Please note that the question was "why", not "if".

Comment: @arkascha - no, what I said is it doesn't work because the image is not in that location, it's somewhere else, and it's impossible for anyone other than the OP to know where that image is.

Comment: @adeneo Sure. You did. Certainly the OP now knows what to do.

Comment: @arkascha - the OP should know what to do, find out what the correct URL for the image is, and noone here can help with that.

Comment: I suggest you use your browsers development console and check what the `src` property actually contains as URL after your code changed it. You can do that either by "inspecting" an img element on the page or by watching the failing requests in the "network" tab.

Comment: What is `chrome.extension` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare resources as [web-accessible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "cat.jpg"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My plugin works now, I see cats everywhere :-)